# Use an aar library cause missing dependencies using api in Gradle 4.x

Tags: android, module, android-gradle-plugin, aar

When I build an app with a *.aar file instead of the module with Gradle 4.x and following the [docu](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation) concerning *implements* and *api*, I expect using *api* the included aar file has all dependencies included, but it hasn't.

When you do

```
git clone https://github.com/hannesa2/aar_dependency
./gradlew clean assembleDebug
```

means

```
dependencies {
    api project(':mylibrary')
```

it works properly.

But when I use insted of lib-module the previous generated *.aar file as dependency

```
 dependencies {
    api 'com.example.my.mylibrary:mylibrary-debug@aar'
```

(in [demo app](https://github.com/hannesa2/aar_dependency) just do)

```
git checkout with_aar
./gradlew clean assembleDebug
```

I run into this

> Task :app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type io.reactivex.ObservableTransformer not present
>           at sun.invoke.util.BytecodeDescriptor.parseSig(BytecodeDescriptor.java:85)
>           at sun.invoke.util.BytecodeDescriptor.parseMethod(BytecodeDescriptor.java:63)
>           at sun.invoke.util.BytecodeDescriptor.parseMethod(BytecodeDescriptor.java:41)
>           at java.lang.invoke.MethodType.fromMethodDescriptorString(MethodType.java:1067)
>           at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.LambdaDesugaring$InvokedynamicRewriter.visitInvokeDynamicInsn(LambdaDesugaring.java:399)
>           at org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor.visitInvokeDynamicInsn(Unknown Source)
>           at org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor.visitInvokeDynamicInsn(Unknown Source)

Because I ordinary run into this with uploading the aar artifacts into our company Maven Nexus, I created this [demo-repo](https://github.com/hannesa2/aar_dependency) to show exactly what's wrong. In demo app or using Maven I see the same issue.

Does someone knows what I did wrong ?

Comment: The aar file **doens't contain** the transitive dependencies.  Publish it in a maven repo

Comment: My aar uses eg. RxJava, this RxJava is already in an other maven. 
So I guess your recommendation "Publish it in a maven repo" is fulfilled, or am I wrong ? 

Is there a way for the aar consumer, to use it without handling eg RxJava dependencies ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was able to solve it. The main issue was Android O with Gradle 4.x using **api**

```
dependencies {
    api 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    api "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$versions.libs.rxAndroid"
```

Most answers are concerning something like this

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mipartner(MavenPublication) {
            groupId '...'
            artifactId '..'
            version 1.0
            artifact "$buildDir/outputs/aar/myLib-release.aar"

            //generate pom nodes for dependencies
            pom.withXml {
                def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
                configurations.compile.allDependencies.each { dependency ->
                    def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', dependency.group)
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', dependency.name)
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('version', dependency.version)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    repositories{
        maven {
            url "https://some.url.com"
        }
    }
}
```

but here in the resulting **.pom* there are no dependencies included, after change this line to **api** the dependencies are included in deployed pom !

```
configurations.api.allDependencies.each { dependency ->
```

after this you can easily consume the aar file

```
dependencies {
    api "com.mylib.net:mylib:1.0"
```

Comment: My understanding is that with `api "com.mylib.net:mylib:1.0"` you consume the published `jar` file, but with `api "com.mylib.net:mylib:1.0@aar"` you consume the published `aar` file. With `aar` I had to add `transitive = true` to make it work, with `jar` it worked like in your case. I'm wondering, if you are adding only `api` dependencies to the pom file, don't you get runtime errors because of missing `implementation` dependencies?