# Gradle Plugin 3.0.1 AAR transitive dependency missing

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, aar

I'm looking to use Firebase Analytics within a library (AAR). Using Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.1, and Gradle 4.1. I've included the firebase dependency as `api`, however, when packaged into the AAR the dependency is missing, and it crashes at runtime in the consuming application (it is not a 'module' within that application). This crash is due to a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics"` exception.

Library Module: `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.0'
    implementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'
}
```

I can get around this by including the `implementation "<firebase>"` line in the consuming application, however, I was of the understanding that `api` would expose as a transitive dependency to the consumer.

I don't want to force the consumer application to implement Firebase, and it's functional when not setting up the `google-play-services.json` file, plugin,  and `app/build.gradle` changes (provided I have the consumer's implementation line).

Using either `implementation <firebase>` or `api <firebase>` within the Library Module, within the same project, the application including it as per: `implementation project(':mylib')` it operates okay, it is solely when using the AAR that the issue occurs.

Additional note, the Module creating the AAR contains native code.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46625186/573042) solved it.